# После обновления библиотеки поддержки и build tools проект вылетает с ошибкой на setContentView

Tags: android, xml

Обновил библиотеку до версии 24.0.0 с версии 23.3.0

После этого ни с того, ни с сего проект начал падать с ошибкой:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.asgard.power, PID: 15025
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asgard.power/com.asgard.power.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
      at com.asgard.power.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.asgard.power.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onCreateDrawableState(AppBarLayout.java:491)
      at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:16502)
      at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:16737)
      at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:16674)
      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4203)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:524)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:215)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:206)
      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:148)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.asgard.power.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Пытался делать Rebuild и Clean - не помогло.

Искал подобное на англоязычном стеке, но в основном находил проблемы с фрагментами.

Так выглядит `gradle` сейчас:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asgard.power"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.4'
}
```

Приведу разметку частично, С appBarLayout

Layout v17+ :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:clickable="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Layout 17v > :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:clickable="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

UPD: `background` :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#1273A8"
                android:centerColor="#52BAD1"
                android:endColor="#1273A8"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42323/discussion-on-question-by-asgard------build-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Новые версии либ обычно глючные, стоит относиться к ним осторожно и не использовать без крайней нужды. В данном случае, видимо, проблема в том, как новые версии работают c `drawable` файлами (сейчас гугл пытается всё под векторы заточить, попутно добавив обратную совместимость - это трудно, отсюда баги).

В вашем случае должно помочь

1. откат compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion до 23
2. buildToolsVersion до 23.0.0
3. версий библиотек поддержки до 23.3.0
4. добавление в gradle уровня проекта

   ```
   android { defaultConfig { vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true } }
   ```
5. Там же версия gradle должна быть 2.x.x
6. Убирание лишних тегов из фона (selector и item)
7. Сделать rebiuld/clean

Comment: А известно что нового в 24.0.0?) я вот обновил, но чет не догнал что именно новое))

Comment: @iFr0z, ну согласно вот [этому](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) ничего там особенного нет. А вот баги новые, конечно, имеются)